# Cannot call klipper methods in dbus with python

Tags: python, dbus

I try to call methods from klipper bus with python. But I could not make it. Here is what i try:

```
>>> import dbus
>>> bus = dbus.SessionBus()
>>> proxy = bus.get_object("org.kde.klipper","/org/kde/klipper")
>>> print proxy
<ProxyObject wrapping <dbus._dbus.SessionBus (session) at 0x7fc249da3bf0> :1.67 /org/kde/klipper at 0x7fc249dc16d0>
>>> iface = dbus.Interface(proxy,"org.kde.klipper.klipper")
>>> print iface
<Interface <ProxyObject wrapping <dbus._dbus.SessionBus (session) at 0x7fc249da3bf0> :1.67 /org/kde/klipper at 0x7fc249dc16d0> implementing 'org.kde.klipper.klipper' at 0x7fc249dc1790>
>>> print iface.getClipboardContents()
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.67:/org/kde/klipper: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: No such object path '/org/kde/klipper'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 140, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 622, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: No such object path '/org/kde/klipper'
```

As you can see it sets both proxy and interface. But I cannot call methods via this interface.

What can I do? What am i doing wrong?

Edit Solved:

Well when i look to "qdbusviewer" I saw the exact path of klipper.
So changing

```
>> proxy = bus.get_object("org.kde.klipper","/org/kde/klipper")
```

this line with this:

```
>>> proxy = bus.get_object("org.kde.klipper","/klipper")
```

Solves the problem.

I hope this post help someone

Comment: After some try, I found the the mistake:
>>> proxy = bus.get_object("org.kde.klipper","/org/kde/klipper") must be:
>>> proxy = bus.get_object("org.kde.klipper","/klipper")
this solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some try, I found the the mistake:
`>>> proxy = bus.get_object("org.kde.klipper","/org/kde/klipper")` 
must be: 
`>>> proxy = bus.get_object("org.kde.klipper","/klipper")` 
this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks quite scarry. It might be simpler to call `qdbus` through `bash`:

```
import os
system("qdbus org.kde.klipper /klipper getClipboardHistoryItem 0")
```

0 is for current selection, 1 is for following one - and so on.